# Using r sf::st_write to non-public schema in PostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, r-sf

I'm trying to write a spatial table to a schema that is not the default public schema in a  PostgreSQL db.

```
library(sf)
library(DBI)
library(RPostgreSQL)
library(spData)

# PostgreSQL DB parameters
host <- "myHost" 
port <- 5432
username <- "myName"
dbname <- "myDb"
password <- "MyPassword"

# Connect to db  
conn <- dbConnect(PostgreSQL(), dbname = dbname, host = host, port = port, user = username, password = password)

st_write(obj = cycle_hire, dsn = conn, Id(schema="myOtherSchema", table = "myCycle")) # Write data to db - currently only writes to default schema

# Disconnect db
dbDisconnect(conn)
```

But this adds my table to the public schema with the name `"myOtherSchema"."myCycle"`.

Also tried above with...

`dbWriteTable(conn = conn, name = "myCycle", value = cycle_hire, Id(schema="mySchema"))`

...substituted for `st_write`, which results in `myCycle` being written to public schema.

What am I doing wrong?

Session info:

```
R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows Server >= 2012 x64 (build 9200)
```

Running PostgreSQL 11.1 on Centos 7 OS.

Comment: I'd try connecting using package  `RPostgres`: conn <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres()), dbname = dbname, host = host, port = port, user = username, password = password)`

Comment: @lbusett there's no package `RPostgres`

Comment: Did you try installing it (`install.packages("RPostgres")` ?

Comment: @lbusett ah ha. See what just google searching brings you. OK ran `conn <- dbConnect(Postgres(), dbname = dbname, host = host, port = port, user = username, password = password)` then `st_write(obj = cycle_hire, dsn = conn, Id(schema="roads_spatial", table = "myCycle")) ` and get `Error in st_write.sf(obj = cycle_hire, dsn = conn, Id(schema = "roads_spatial", : no st_write method available for dsn of class list`

Comment: Scratch that, my bad: @lbusett Ran `conn <- dbConnect(Postgres(), dbname = dbname, host = host, port = port, user = username, password = password)` then `st_write(obj = cycle_hire, dsn = conn, Id(schema="roads_spatial", table = "myCycle")) ` and success! Many thanks - I wasn't aware of `RPostgres`. Post a solution and I'll accept.

Comment: glad it helped. Was just thinking that with `RPostgreSQL` you could try something on the lines: st_write(obj = cycle_hire, dsn = conn, layer = c("myOtherSchema", "myCycle")) (see https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/557)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This happens because you are connecting to the db via package `RPostgreSQL`, but the syntax used for specifying table and schema is that used with connections made with package `RPostgres`. You can solve this using:

```
    require(RPostgres)
    conn <- dbConnect(Postgres(), dbname = dbname, host = host, port = port, 
                      user = username, password = password)
    st_write(obj = cycle_hire, dsn = conn, Id(schema="roads_spatial", table = "myCycle"))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
require(RPostgres)
    conn <- dbConnect(Postgres(), dbname = dbname, host = host, port = port, 
                      user = username, password = password)
    st_write(obj = cycle_hire, dsn = conn, Id(schema="roads_spatial", table = "myCycle"))
```

Using Postgres 12, I get a table `"roads_spatial"."mycycle"` in public which is not the intended result ?

So a simple roundabout way is to write to public and then use

```
dbExecute(
        conn,
        "ALTER TABLE myCycle SET SCHEMA roads_spatial")
```

---

```
 packageVersion("RPostgres") #[1] '1.2.0'
 packageVersion("DBI")       #[1] '1.1.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

Also using Postgres 12, I initially ran into the same problem as @Cedric (a new table in public named the equivalent of "roads_spatial."mycycle". I was finally able to successfully create a new table named "mycycle" in the "roads_spatial" schema (or the equivalent in my database) with the following:

```
st_write(obj = cycle_hire, dsn = conn, layer = c("roads_spatial", "mycycle"), delete_layer = TRUE)
```