# st_write cannot add to non-public schema

Tags: r, geometry, postgis, r-sf

I am trying to write data into a non-public schema using function st_write from sf package

I cannot change the following way I connect to the db, as it will break all other functions -

```
create_db_connection <- function(host, dbuser, dbpassword){
  drv = RPostgreSQL::PostgreSQL()
  DBuser = dbuser
  DBhost = host
  DBport = "5432"
  DBpassword = dbpassword
  db = RPostgreSQL::dbConnect(drv, dbname = "DIFM", user = DBuser, host = DBhost, port = DBport, password = DBpassword)

  return(db)
}
```

Using the above connection, I have tried the following -

```
1. sf::st_write(obj = obj_geom, dsn = db, layer = c(schema_name, "temp_geometrytable"), row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)

2. sf::st_write(obj = obj_geom, dsn = db, DBI::Id(schema=schema_name, table = "temp_geometrytable"), row.names = FALSE, append = TRUE)
```

But all of these keep adding into the public schema, but i want to dynamically provide schema name and then add the object into the database into a non-public schema

Comment: Etienne Racine, one of the sf authors, is the person to ask. You may want to raise an issue with sf on github, and tag him.

Comment: A good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54202315/using-r-sfst-write-to-non-public-schema-in-postgresql?rq=1